Trouble Setting and Storing Cookies in Browser with React App Deployed on GitHub Pages and Node.js Backend on Render
I'm currently facing an issue with setting and storing cookies in the browser while using a React app deployed on GitHub Pages and a Node.js backend hosted on Render. Here's the setup and the problem I'm encountering:
Setup:

Frontend: React app deployed on GitHub Pages
Backend: Node.js server hosted on Render.
Problem: If I use secure:false, cookies set by the backend are received by the browser on GitHub Pages, but they are not actually being set. If I use secure:true, the cookies do not arrive at all on the client.

Backend:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const {passport} = require('./utils/auth');
const userRoutes = require('./router/users');
const roomRoutes = require('./router/rooms');
const socketEvents = require("./utils/socket");

const testHost = 'http://localhost:3000';
const prodHost = 'https://[GITHUB_PAGE]';

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const host = isProd ? prodHost : testHost;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: host,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
const mongoURI = '[MONGO_URL]';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: host,
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(session({
    secret: '[SECRET]',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: isProd,
        sameSite: isProd ? 'None' : 'Lax',
        domain: isProd ? '.onrender.com': "localhost",
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/rooms", roomRoutes);

socketEvents(io);

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Database connected");
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    });
})
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

Frontend request:
import axios from 'axios';

const prodHost = 'https://[RENDER_SITE].onrender.com';
const testHost = 'http://localhost:1234';

const host = process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === 'production' ? prodHost : testHost;

const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: host,
    withCredentials: true
});

Both github and Render are using https, so I am not sure why I am not receiving the cookies

Found the solution, I was deploying through a backend that used a proxy and had to set proxy:true in the session options as per this answer: Secure CookieSession when using iisnode
